# Laravel 4 How to Filter a Polymorphic Table

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have a polymorphic table called 'Item':

```
    Schema::create('items', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->text('itemable_type')->nullable();
        $table->string('itemable_id')->nullable();
        $table->integer('subject_id')->nullable();
        $table->integer('user_id')->nullable();
        $table->integer('new')->nullable();
        $table->integer('school')->nullable();
        $table->string('private')->nullable();
        $table->text('snippet')->nullable();
        $table->string('elementSubject')->nullable();
        $table->integer('follow_id')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Also have a table called 'Follow':

```
    Schema::create('follows', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('subject_id')->nullable();
        $table->integer('teacher_id')->nullable();
        $table->integer('user_id')->nullable();
        $table->integer('effort')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Also have a table called 'Subject':

```
    Schema::create('subjects', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name')->nullable();
        $table->integer('studentID')->nullable();
        $table->integer('teacherID')->nullable();
        $table->integer('schoolID')->nullable();
        $table->integer('memberID')->nullable();
        $table->string('private')->nullable();
        $table->integer('creator')->nullable();
        $table->softDeletes();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

They are linked together like this in my model:

```
    class Follow extends Eloquent {
        protected $guarded = array();

        public static $rules = array();

        public function subjects()
        {
            return $this->hasMany('Subject');
        }
```

I like to filter the 'Item' list based on the 'Subjects' the 'User' is following. What would my Eloquent look like?

I have this filtering on the 'School' but I want to filter it on what the user is 'Following'

```
    $follows = Follow::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get();
    $items = Item::where('school', Auth::user()->school)
    ->where('private', 'false')
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
    ->get();
```

Comment: You want flat array of items, or whole relation through subjects?

Comment: Hoping to get an array of items.